# Intuition for Poisson distribution's recurrence?

Tags: poisson-distribution, intuition

The Poisson distribution has a simple recurrence relation: given a success rate $\lambda$, the probability of getting $k + 1$ successes in some time $t$ satisfies

$P_{k+1}(t) = \frac{(\lambda t)^{k+1} e^{-\lambda t}}{(k+1)!} = \frac{\lambda t}{k+1} P_{k}(t)$.

I see why the recurrence works algebraically, but is there a nice way to see it intuitively?

Comment: There may be many different answers to this.  Last year I posted one such answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/215253/919.

Comment: whuber gives a very detailed answer in the linked question. What one call intuitive can be subjective but there is enough there so that it may satisfy your intuition.

Comment: The Poisson counts events.  I think it is more general to call them events rather than successes.

Comment: @whuber beautiful! That's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Althought the answer from the other question applies here, I'm not sure if this is really a duplicate -  perhaps there are other nice ways to see this recurrence, not directly related to exponential summands