# Poisson distribution: why does time between events follow an exponential distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution

I was reading an [article](https://www.datascience.com/blog/intro-to-predictive-modeling-for-customer-lifetime-value), and came across the following:

> **Purchase count follows a Poisson distribution with rate λ.** In other
>   words, the timing of these purchases is somewhat random, but the rate
>   (in counts/unit time) is constant. In turn, this implies that the
>   inter-purchase time at the customer level should follow an exponential
>   distribution.

It's been quite a while since I did any statistics so I am struggling with the definitions of a Poisson distribution. What I understand by the "rate is constant" is that if a customer purchases 1 thing on average in a week, they purchase 4 things on average in a four-week period. Is this correct?

Where I believe I am confused is with the final sentence. Is this saying that the time between a customers purchases would grow exponentially as time goes on? Doesn't this contradict the idea that we have a constant rate of purchase?

Comment: For a full account of this, including definitions, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214421.  For related posts, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+poisson+exponential+uniform+-regression+-likelihood+-chi+score%3A2  Another useful search (focusing on "memoryless") is https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=memoryless+exponential+poisson+score%3A2.

Comment: $${}$$ "if a customer purchases 1 thing on average in a week, they purchase 4 things on average in a four-week period. Is this correct?" $\textbf{Yes}.$ $${}$$ "Is this saying that the time between a customers purchases would grow exponentially as time goes on?" $\textbf{No},$ that's not what it means at all. $\qquad$

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $X_t$ be the number of arrivals in the Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ between time $0$ and time $t\ge0.$ Then we have
$$
\Pr(X_t=x) = \frac{(\lambda t)^x e^{-\lambda t}}{x!} \text{ for } x=0,1,2,3,\ldots
$$

Let $T$ be the time until the first arrival.

Then the following two events are really both the **same** event:
$$
\Big[ X_t=0\Big]. \qquad \Big[ T>t \Big].
$$
So they both have the **same** probability. Thus
$$
\Pr(T>t) = \Pr(X_t=0) = \frac{(\lambda t)^0 e^{-\lambda t}}{0!} = e^{-\lambda t}.
$$
So
$$
\Pr(T>t) = e^{-\lambda t} \text{ for } t\ge0.
$$
That says $T$ is exponentially distributed.

Answer (score 4):

[Exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) doesn't imply that time between events grows exponentially. All it tells you is that probability to wait longer between events declines very quickly with waiting time. The probability density is:$$\lambda e^{-\lambda t}$$ where $\lambda$ is Poisson intensity, i.e. average number of events in unit of time, and $t$ is the waiting time. The average waiting time is obviously $1/\lambda$.