# Why person-years follow a Poisson ditribution?

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution, variable

While studing poisson distributions, this simple question came to my mind:

Poisson distribution are made of variables which only have integer numbers and are always >0 (as an example: number of myocardial infarction in an hospital).

It is usually said that this variable still follow a poisson distribution when taking into account the follow-up period by the person-years unit, instead of just number of events, but why? Aren't person-years units non-integer, since the can also have values of, as an example, 0.8 or 2.5?

Example: https://www.statsdirect.com/help/rates/poisson_rate_ci.htm

Comment: Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/544301

Comment: @PeterO. thanks for your answer but, even if there is a clear explanation of how poisson models work, it doesn't actually answer my question (or at least I cannot find a similar example)

Comment: It's only a comment, not an answer, and it merely shows a question that may be related to this one.

Comment: "It is usually said" -- is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it boils down to that, following your example, a count of 14 events over 400 person-years, gives a Poisson rate parameter estimate of 0.35 events per person-year. So if you were to track one person over a year, you'd have a 70% chance of observing no events, 25% of one event, 4% of two events, & so on; on average 0.35 events, but no non-integer counts.

It's a consequence of the memorylessness of the Poisson process & that the sum of independent Poisson random variables is a Poisson r.v. with a rate equal to the sum of their individual rates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution! Hope this could help also other students out there!

Comment: @ClaudioLaudani: You're welcome