# the difference between poisson distribution and poisson process in terms of application

Tags: poisson-process, poisson-distribution

What is the difference between poisson distribution and poisson process? I don't know technically in terms of application.

I know the value of lambda = 8 and k = 3, for 100 variates, how can I creates poisson distribution?

thank you.

Read a definition on poisson process;

[image]

Comment: My answer to the question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214421 addresses this question.