# Radioactive decay as a Poisson process

Tags: probability, self-study, poisson-distribution, independence, poisson-process

I am trying to grapple with the following question as I self-study from the chapter on probability in my quantum mechanics textbook (Ballentine's *Quantum Mechanics: A Modern Development*). Unfortunately, it has been a long time since I've studied probability and my memory is hazy.

> A source emits particles at an average rate of $\alpha$ particles per second; however, each emission is stochastically independent of all previous emission events. Calculate the probability that exactly $n$ particles will be emitted within a time interval $t$.

Now I have the vague notion that I should be able to situate this question in the context of a Poisson process but I'm not quite sure how to go about it. In particular, all I can deduce so far is the following:

> We interpret the problem statement as saying that the probability of an emission in any infinitesimal interval $dt$ of time is $\alpha \ dt$. Then we can argue that the probability $P_1$ of the first emission happening in the interval $[t,t+dt)$ is  the probability of the event in which no emissions happen in the interval $[0,t)$ **and** we have an emission in the interval $[t,t+dt)$. That is, we have
> $$P_1 = \left(\lim_{N \to \infty} \left(1-\frac{\alpha t}{N}\right)^N\right)\left(\alpha \ dt \right) = \alpha e^{-\alpha t}dt := f(t)dt$$
> where $f(t)$ is the corresponding pdf (and we've just shown that it's exponential).

It's not clear to me how to generalize this statement about the random variable $T_1$ (time until first emission) to the pmf/pdf of the random variable $n_t$ (the number of emissions in a time interval $t$). To use the theory of point Poisson processes I think I need to show the definition: "a Poisson point process has the property that the number of points in a bounded region of the process's underlying space is a Poisson-distributed random variable." But it's not clear to me how I can use my $f(t)$ (for the RV $T_1$) to show this fact. Any help with showing this fact (and ideally basically helping me work through the whole problem) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the condition "*A source emits particles at an average rate of $\alpha$ particles per second; however, each emission is stochastically independent of all previous emission events.*" is sufficient (or is sufficiently accurate) to determine the counting process as a Poisson process.  It sounds similar to Condition $3^\circ$ in Section 23 of *Probability and Measure* by Patrick Billingsley.  If so, the same reference provided the proof why this characterization is a Poisson process.

Comment: The same reference also provides a characterization that allows you to derive the Poisson process via differential equations (Condition $4^\circ$), which may be of your interest.

Comment: Does https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/214421 address your questions?

Comment: Thank you to all commenters. I think your collective comments answer my question.