# Distribution of a process

Tags: distributions, poisson-process

I'm having trouble on solving this problem. Given a Poisson process X with parameter lambda and, indipendently,  a random variable T with density f(t)=$\theta*e^{(-\theta t)}$, compute the distribution of X(T). I have no idea of how to do it since I don't really understand the meaning of X(T). Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you considered [searching our site for the answer?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22poisson+process%22+definition)  I give a basic definition at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/215253/919, for instance.  I suspect you might be working with an unusual definition of Poisson process, though, because according to standard definitions, $X(t)$ is almost surely zero for any time $t.$